# What is the meaning of a conductor in equilibrium?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, definition, conductors, equilibrium

Electric field lines are always perpendicular to the surface of a conductor in equilibrium.
what is the meaning of a conductor in equilibrium?

Answer (score 0):

A conductor in electrostatic equilibrium is one that satisfies the following properties:
1.The electric field is zero everywhere inside the conductor.
2.Any net charge on it must reside entirely on its surface.
Any conductor that satisfies these two properties is said to be in electrostatic equilibrium.
The electric field lines are always perpendicular to the surface of such a conductor, as if the electric field had a non-zero tangential component, the charges on the surface of the conductor would flow and violate the equilibrium condition.

Answer (score 0):

You have an isolated conductor. You give some charge to it. This charge is free to move on conductor. The char will move until it reaches an 'equilibrium' condition. That is, net force on all free electrons is zero and they cease to move. This is called the **equilibrium condition**.

The condition where charges are still moving while searching for equilibrium is called **transient state**.

For a typical conductor transient state will be over in millisecond to microseconds.